# Pitot tube airflow speed measurement

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, aerodynamics, bernoulli-equation

how pitot tube can specify the airflow at aircrafts. according to formula airflow speed is related with fluid density. when aircraft passes through clouds it meets different density of fluid than passing through clean weather.

[[image: pitot tube air speed formula]

Answer (score 2):

The pitot tube feeds a pressure difference to the Airspeed indicator in the cockpit. The instrument is calibrated on the assumption that the incoming air is at standard temp and pressure. Therefore the reading will vary, as you stated, depending on the air density.
The actual reading is known as IAS (Indicated Airspeed). In light aircraft there will be an 'outside air temperature gauge' which, along with knowing the altitude, gives the ability to apply a correction factor to the IAS to adapt for the variation from STP of the air. This needs to be applied to the IAS if the speed is to be used for navigation purposes.

HOWEVER it should be noted that the aerodynamic performance of the plane ALSO depends on the density of the air, and hence the operating manual speeds such as stall speed and flaps speed can be read directly from IAS and are not dependent on corrections.